# Passing Arguments to C functions from x86

Tags: assembly, x86

I am learning assembly, and I am having trouble understanding what is wrong this my code. I am trying to pass a value (4 in this example) to a function in C, which just prints this value. But, when I run the code, it prints 1 instead of 4. I am running 64-bit on Ubuntu, and I am compiling with GCC.

Here is the assembly:

```
.extern myprint

  .text
  .global main
main:   
        push  $4
        call   myprint 

        mov    $1, %eax
        int    $0x80
```

And here is the function in C:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int myprint(int n) {
  printf("%d\n", n);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: what's the error??

Comment: That is 32 bit code. Make sure you use `gcc -m32`.

Comment: @Jester Okay, thank you. Do you also know how I can change it to 64-bit code?

Comment: Use the 64 bit conventions. TL;DR: `push %rbp; movl $4, %edi; call myprint; pop %rbp; ret`.

Comment: Or even just `movl $4, %edi; jmp myprint` in this simple case :)

Comment: @Jester All right, awesome. Thank you!

Comment: Also related: [What happens if you use the 32-bit int 0x80 Linux ABI in 64-bit code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46087730)  And BTW, it prints `1` because you leave EDI unmodified, so it still holds main's `argc` argument when you call your print function.